# Can I use Data Annotations or Fluent to convert a value between data store and entity class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working with an existing [poorly designed] database which stores a dollar amount as an integer (ie. $10.99 == 1099) in the database.  I want my entity class to treat this value as a decimal so that consuming code doesn't have to do the translation.

**Is there a way to convert the value to and from integer to decimal and then back using Data Annotations or Fluent configuration?**

In the meantime I am using a hack which essentially "wraps" the integer property with a decimal property that handles the translation.

```
    [Column("intTotal")]
    public virtual int TotalAsInt { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual decimal Total
    {
        get { return (decimal) TotalAsInt/100; }
        set { TotalAsInt = (int)(value*100); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert the value to and from integer to decimal and then back using Data Annotations or Fluent configuration?

Not as far as I know. Your solution looks good.

You could hide `TotalAsInt` by making it a `private` property, but then you couldn't use it in `IQueryable` methods like `Where` or `Select`.

So, I would go with your solution until you can fix the database.

Comment: If I make TotalAsInt private it will hide its accessibility from Entity Framework, thereby eliminating the data binding, won't it?

Comment: There are ( [ways](http://blog.cincura.net/232731-mapping-private-protected-properties-in-entity-framework-4-x-code-first/) ), but it's probably not worth the effort and compromise.

Comment: To me it would make more sense to hide accessibility through an assembly layer/abstraction but that is overkill for my needs on this project.  Too bad EF doesn't have a way to do type conversion via configuration.  I'll wait for a while before marking this as the answer since I still have hope for a possible config-based solution. :)